# When will Debian switch to Linux 4.x? ( and support the live kernel patching ? )

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

Wikipedia says that current Debian 8.2 Jessie is based on kernel
3.16.0, so I was wondering when a native version based on kernel 4.x
would be released and if the live kernel patching will be there as
feature with the 4.x.

I searched for a Debian roadmap on Google, but I found nothing about
the kernel.

Comment: FYI: Kernel 4.2.6 is currently (2015-11) in Debian/testing and Debian/unstable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it is still not a given, officially most probably the last quarter of 2016, with the release of Debian 9. In the meanwhile, you can start using testing, compile it yourself or using a version compiled by someone else. I am using armbian in a Raspberry Pi like-device (Lamobo R1), which is Jessie, and using a v4.x put together by the armbian guys. On my Intel servers at work I plan to go soon to v4 too with Debian 8.

Answer (score 11):

If you need live-patching, you can try the 4.x Linux kernels  from http://backports.debian.org/. However, you probably need to create the live patches by yourself or use third-party patches.

Backport-packages are usually taken from Debian `testing` and re-compiled for the current `stable` (jessie).

Comment: Nice solution thank you, yes indeed my guess is have an auto update linux with automatic kernel patching ;)

Comment: thanks for remembering it, I came here again to add this tidbit to my answer, and you had it already here.

Comment: However, the Debian kernel team did not promise to create live patches accompanying the regular kernel updates, as that would require a substantial amount of work and they're lacking manpower already. You can apply your own or third party patches, though.

Comment: @FerencWágner thanks, I extended the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Debian 9 "Stretch" will be released with Linux 4.9.  The Stretch repositories (testing) now have [**Linux 4.9**](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-amd64).

Live kernel patching may be possible, the [kpatch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/kpatch) tool is in the Stretch repository.  However, the Debian kernel team might not necessarily provide the necessary patch files.

The [original plan as of 2016-03-03](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch#Before_the_release) was to release with **Linux 4.10** -- its release plan was *stretched* by two months (groan) to allow this.  However, [on 2016-08-13 it was decided that Stretch will release with **Linux 4.9 LTS**](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2016/08/msg00099.html) since it is the Linux kernel LTS release.

Comment: Interesting, please update your answer as well as more info will become available.